# Changing Specific Values In a 2D array Using For Loops and If statements without a known Index

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, nested-lists

I have a 2D array from a geotiff file. See the example array below:

```
example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                 [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                 [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I am attempting to write a program that will change the specific number greater than 1 in each nested list to the 'value + 100'.

With the help of others see the below working code snippet that correctly changes the first value in each list greater than 1 to +100 of the value.

```
for l in example_array:
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > 1:
            l[i] -= 100
            break
```

If I wanted to change exclusively the second value in each list greater than 1 I attempted the below incorrect code snippet:

```
for l in example_array:
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x > 1:
            if x > 1:
                l[i] -= 100
                break
```

The thought process here is that if I added another `if x>1:` argument to the `for loop` it would start at the first number greater than 1 then move to the second value greater than 1 with the next `if x>1:`. That is not the case here. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correctly change the second number greater that 1 such that is displays the correct `example_array` below?:

```
    example_array = [[ 0,  1, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                     [ 2, 101, 1,  2, 0, 0, 0], 
                     [ 0,  3, 101, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                     [ 4, 101, 1,  4, 0, 0, 0], 
                     [ 0,  5, 101, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                     [ 0,  1, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `l[i] += 100`? Hint: your added *if* has absolutely no effect.

Comment: Greater than 1 or >= 1? In your first list, there are no elements greater than 1, yet you've incremented the element after the first `1` value. Your logic doesn't make sense. How would you handle `[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1]` for example?

Comment: Also, why are you using `enumerate` instead of just iterating over the list elements directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed for this response that you meant >=1 and not >1, judging by the final example you provided.

this is not the pretties solution but i guess it is what you're looking for:

```
for l in example_array:
    c = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if x >= 1:
            if c == 1:
                l[i] += 100
                break
            c += 1
```

However you can do it much more efficiently using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Assuming example_array is a list of lists
for row in example_array:
    row_np = np.array(row)  # Convert list to NumPy array for the comparison
    positive_indices = np.where(row_np >= 1)[0]  # Get indices of elements greater than or equal to 1
    if len(positive_indices) >= 2:  # Check if there are at least two elements greater than or equal to 1
        row[positive_indices[1]] += 100  # Add 100 to the second element greater than or equal to 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the numpy method to start from the end of a list of elements and work it such that the the second to last number >= 1 is changed in addition to the second number >= 1?

Comment: ofc, the np.where function returns all index that fulfill the criteria. so if you want to change the 2nd to last, you can either just add another row, that goes into the index -2. like so: "row[positive_indices[-2]] += 100"